# EditText Change style

Tags: android, android-edittext

On my login page for my app, I have two edit texts, One for password and one for username. I want to change the way the look from the default to something how it is in the link below.

> [image]

Code in xml file

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" 
            android:hint="Username"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:textColor="#333745"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:textColor="#333745"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

Comment: use shapes inside drawable

Comment: Easiest way is create an image with desired shape and size ,and put it as background for the edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create round.xml file in /drawable folder of your android project and add the following code

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<shape xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221; >
<corners android:radius=”5dp” />
<stroke
android:width=”1dp”
android:color=”#44433A” />
<solid android:color=”#FFF” />
</shape>
```

Add this xml as a background for EditText Widget

```
<EditText
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:background=”@drawable/round”
android:hint=”Round Corners”
android:padding=”8dp” />
```

and You can use more than style from [HERE](http://letustech.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/customedittext/)

Comment: Welcome >>> can you set me answer as correct answer please.

Comment: I would love to but that requires a reputation of 15 and I only have a reputation of 6.

Comment: @user3359387 You can up vote the answer whichever helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Just create xml file in your `res/drawable` folder and paste the below code.
Try to apply the below shape in your `EditText`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#EBEBEB"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
  android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
  <padding android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Apply it in your `EditText` as background image below:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:textColor="#333745"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

You can apply the color in shape according to your need.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then, just reference this drawable in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</LinearLayout>
```